# Consolidate Google Calendar Accounts

Tags: google-calendar

I'd like to know how to consolidate the events from multiple Google calendars into one.

I have a number of Google app accounts, for various businesses etc, but as I'm only one person I'd like to use only 1 calendar. This is fine when I'm entering events in myself, but if I'm emailed an invitation and accept that I'm attending, then the event automatically gets added to the calendar of the Google account that I'm currently signed into.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue. I have just shared each calendar with each account. This way it doesn't really matter what calendar it is stored on, I will always see it. It is also very easy to move them between calendars as well.

Exports and Imports really help when getting things setup at first. Just make sure you back everything up before you start.